# UITableViewCell get subview height with auto-layout

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass on which I'm using auto-layout, and I want to get the height of a `UILabel` subview once the auto-layout process has been completed.

I tried `layoutSubviews` and getting the `frame` property of my `UILabel`, but this seemed to be the old height of the label before it was recycled.

I then tried to override `layoutIfNeeded` but I found it was never called.

How can I get the frames of my `UITableViewCell` subviews once auto-layout is completed and the constraints have been applied? Surely this should be really simple!

Comment: Does "tried layoutSubviews" refer to the table cell's layoutSubviews method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the label is an immediate subview of the table cell's content view, then my quess is that you could access the final, on-screen value of the label's bounds in the `layoutSubviews` method for the content view of the table cell (rather than the `layoutSubviews` method of the table cell itself).

However, if your label is not multi-lined, then simply grab the label's height from its `attributedText` property at anytime as follows:

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = label.attributedText;
CGFloat labelHeight = ceilf(attrString.size.height);
```

Alternatively, you could use the label's `font` property to determine the label's height (again, only if the label is not multi-lined):

```
UIFont *font = label.font;
CGFloat labelHeight = ceilf(font.lineHeight);
```

If your label is multi-lined, then the best choice for calculating the line height is as follows:

```
// but you have to know the label's width
CGFloat labelWidth = …
NSAttributedString *attrString = label.attributedText;
CGRect rect = [attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
CGFloat labelHeight = ceilf(rect.size.height);
```

You would calculate the label's width manually. Often it's the main view's bounds width minus some fixed amount for horizontal spacing margins.